# Git, adding a new repository

Tags: git

I am using Bitbucket, I created a new repository on their website called `Project`.

Now within a folder called `Project` on my desktop, I run:

`$ git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/group/project.git`

However, when I push to this origin after comitting files, it changes the path instead of just uploading the files within the folder.

E.g., instead of uploading just the files within the `Project` folder, so when I click on "source" it's the same as viewing the `Project` folder on my desktop, it's adding two extra folders (Desktop & Project) like so:

**Desktop/Project/...**

Why is this? When I click on repository source on the website, I should only see all the files like I would if I was inside my `Project` folder on my desktop. But instead there is a `Desktop` folder, then within that a `Project` folder, THEN there are my files.

What am I overlooking? I hope I explained properly.

Comment: where is the .git folder?

Comment: yes, check that u r using this command inside the Project folder. means u need to initialise the git(make it as git repo) then start using the command

Comment: @Paul There is one `.git` folder on my computer, and it's within `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\folder1\folder2`.

Comment: @MayankShukla I think this may be the issue. I never initialized (`git init`) within the `Project` folder. I simply created the repository online, then ran the command above in my question. I think this is my error. Sorry I'm new to this. But even if this is the case, how would it upload anything at all without a `.git` file anywhere in a parent directory above the `Project` folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to properly initialize your working repository

```
git init        # this will initialize git repo(do it in Project folder at your desktop)
```

You have added the remote properly as :

```
git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/group/project.git
```

Even you can name your remote as per your choice :

```
 git remote add <remote name> <your repo url>   # link the remote url and name it
```

Now you can add your changes and commit the code and push it up

You can go through https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 and have some try-outs